# What does "Daimadoshi" mean in "Dai no Daibouken" (Dragon Quest: The Adventure of Dai)?

Tags: japanese-language, dragon-quest-adventure-of-dai

One of my favorite character in *Dragon Quest: The Adventure of Dai* is Pop the Magician. Toward the end of the series, he battles with Hadler's chess squad and has a one-on-one fight with the horse Sigma. Pop demonstrates great magical skills and Sigma asked him if he is a sage. Pop answers that he doesn't like the title of sage and had chosen a title for himself: **Daimadoshi**.

**What does Daimadoshi mean in the universe of the manga?**

The manga obviously uses a lot of Japanese, even if it is set in a fantasy universe. Does Daimadoshi mean anything in Japanese? Or is it a made-up for the manga?

*Note*: I hesitated before posting this question on Japanese.se, because I am not sure whether daimadoshi is a Japanese word (or made up from Japanese terms like Tenchimato) or a word from the manga's universe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Dai* means something along the lines of "grand, big" and *madoushi* means "sorcerer" or "wizard", with *shi* being his title (assumedly Mr.). So in essence, he is naming himself "Mr. Grand Wizard"

Comment: shi is not used as a title here, especially not as an honorific (氏).

Answer (score 3):

The title is "大魔道師" or "大魔道士" (Daimadoushi) which more or less means Great Sorcerer. 魔道 (madou) and 魔法 (mahou) both can mean magic, but the former has a more occult nuance to to it (i.e. raw magic vs refined magic). The former literally means the "path/way of magic" while the latter is more so the "art/law of magic".